# Cart ID in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on integrating a 3rd party checkout, and discovered a security hole that i need help closing.  Basically the checkout process is like this:

1. if certain conditions are met, when the customer clicks "checkout" they items in the cart get scraped and they are redirected to the 3rd party site.
2. they fill out their customer information and payment information
3. the payment is processed
4. after the payment is confirmed, they are redirected back to the merchant site
5. the order is processed programatically using the items currently in the cart and the customer receives their confirmation
6. Everybody is happy

The problem comes if someone edits the cart anytime during steps 2-4, Magento believes the new cart contents are what they paid for.

I'm not very familiar with how magento saves quotes, but i'm hoping that there is a "cart ID" or something like that which represents the specific cart with its specific content, and that changes when something is added/deleted/edited in the cart. Then I can compare the number from when they left, to the number when they get back and make sure there's no fraud.

So my questions are:

-Is there such a number?

-Where is it stored and how is it retrieved?

-Can it simply be loaded based on the number to repopulate the cart with the items in there at the time they were redirected to the 3rd party?

-If my plan won't work, why and is there a better way?

-what is your favorite food that is NOT from your native country.  Mine is Pork Sinagang from the Philippines.

Thanks for the help guys.  I wouldn't be able to get through all this without the answers here.

-Matt

Edit:
Some clarification -

1. customer click on "view cart" or something like that to see the cart (if they instead go to the checkout, they are redirected back to the cart if their geoIP is international)
2. they can review the items in the cart, then click checkout

   2a. if their geoIP is domestic they go to the merchant's checkout

   2b. if their geoIP is international then jQuery scrapes the item details and sends them to the hosted checkout.  This is the point I would like to either "freeze" the items in the cart, or get an ID number that will let me check that the cart is identical when they return.
3. The order is confirmed either on whichever checkout they used, and they are directed to a success controller.

This process was determined before I started developing for them, and for whatever reason they don't want it changed.

Answer (score 0):

### Structure

Magento has 3 different structures for the Checkout & Sales workflows:

0. Cart and CartItems
1. Quote and QuoteItems
2. Order and OrderItems

The Quote is the place where things are stored while the customer is completing his personal details, addresses, payment options and while he is visiting the payment gateway or whatever else.

### Workflow

The Cart is converted into a Quote and you are actually paying for a Quote. The Quote is converted into an Order once your payment is confirmed (when you are redirected back from the payment gateway).

The Cart => Quote => Order conversion workflow is designed to prevent exactly what you are describing and it also helps in the bookkeeping of the correct price of a product (which could change in the future).

### Attempting to circumvent this protection

When you click on the order confirmation button (and get redirected to the payment gateway) your Cart information is converted into Quote information (to which a lot of customer information and address info is added).

If you circle back and try to continue editing the Cart you should see that your cart is now empty (having been converted to a Quote) and if you try to add new products to the Cart, a new Cart will be created with a different ID corresponding to a different Quote and so on and so forth.

### Your situation

If you can circumvent this protection on your current Magento install please try and reproduce the same steps on a fresh Magento install (original Magento code, separate database, freshly installed).

I doubt it would reproduce since I've used similar use-cases in Magento 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8 but if it does reproduce please create a bug-report on Magento official channels because this would be a high security risk.

Comment: Emergency appendectomy so I'm a bit late getting back to this.

Edit: why does hitting enter submit?  I hate that.

The problem I'm having is that the transfer from the cart when they first click on "checkout."  From what I can tell this means the cart never gets converted to a quote until my controller when they return.  

I've considered making an ajax call (since it's java that is making the transfer happen) to convert it to a quote, but i'm not sure how effective this would be since that's a bit outside my limited experience. 

I'm not sure what my other options are or which would be best.

Comment: First observation: Java =/= JavaScript

Comment: Secondly we need to differentiate between "checkout" and "order confirmation". Checkout buttons on the site should be the ones leading you to see the items in your cart and then allowing you to enter your delivery/invoice data. After you complete all of these forms you reach the end of the N-stage checkout process and see the "confirm order" button (right after selecting the payment).

Comment: added a bit to the question above to explain the process better